# Possible multiplications of k distinct factors with largest possible factor n

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

Let **M(n,k)** be the **sum** of all possible **multiplications** of **k** **distinct** factors with **largest** possible factor **n**, where **order is irrelevant**.

For example, **M(5,3) = 225** , because:

- 1*2*3 = 6
- 1*2*4 = 8
- 1*2*5 = 10
- 1*3*4 = 12
- 1*3*5 = 15
- 1*4*5 = 20
- 2*3*4 = 24
- 2*3*5 = 30
- 2*4*5 = 40
- 3*4*5 = 60

**6+8+10+12+15+20+24+30+40+60 = 225.**

One can easily notice that there are **C(n,k)** such multiplications, corresponding to the number of ways one can pick **k** objects out of **n** possible objects. In the example above, **C(5,3) = 10** and there really are 10 such multiplications, stated above.

The question can also be visualized as possible **n-sized** sets containing exactly **k 0's**, where each cell that does not contain 0 inside it, has the value of its **index+1** inside it. For example, one possible such set is **{0,2,3,0,5}.** From here on, one needs to multiply the values in the set that are different than 0.

My approach is a recursive algorithm. Similiarly to the above definition of 
**M(n,k),** I define **M(n,j,k)** to be the sum of all possible multiplications of exactly **k** distinct factors with largest possible factor **n**, **AND SMALLEST** possible factor **j**. Hence, my approach would yield the desired value if ran on 
**M(n,1,k).** So I start my recursion on **M(n,1,k),** with the following code, written in Java:

```
public static long M (long n, long j, long k)
{
    if (k==1)
        return usefulFunctions.sum(j, n);
    for (long i=j;i<=n-k+1+1;i++)
        return i*M(n,i+1,k-1);
}
```

Explanation to the code:

Starting with, for example, **n=5 , j=1, k=3**, the algorithm will continue to run as long as we need more factors, **(k>=1),** and it is made sure to run only distinct factors thanks to the for loop, which increases the minimal possible value **j** as more factors are added. The loop runs and decreases the number of needed factors as they are 'added', which is achieved through applying 
**M(n,j+1,k-1).** The **j+1** assures that the factors will be distinct because the minimal value of the factor increases, and **k-1** symbolizes that we need 1 less factor to add.

The function **'sum(j,n)'** returns the value of the sum of all numbers starting from **j** untill **n**, so **sum(1,10)=55**. This is done with a proper, elegant and simple mathematical formula, with no loops: **sum(j,n) = (n+1)*n/2 - (i-1)*i/2**

```
public static long sum (long i, long n)
{
    final long s1 = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    final long s2 = i * (i - 1) / 2;
    return s1 - s2 ;
}
```

The reason to apply this sum when **k=1**, I will explain with an example:
Say we have started with 1*2. Now we need a third factor, which can be either of 3,4,5. Because all multiplications: 1*2*3, 1*2*4, 1*2*5 are valid, we can return **1*2*(3+4+5) = 1*2*sum(3,5) = 24**.

Similiar logic explains the coefficient **"i"** next to the **M(n,j+1,k-1).** 
say we have now the sole factor 2. Hence we need 2 more factors, so we multiply 2 by the next itterations, which should result in:
**2*(3*sum(4,5) + 4*sum(5,5))**

However, for a reason I can't explain yet, the code doesn't work. It returns wrong values and also has "return" issues that cause the function not to return anything, don't know why.

This is the reason i'm posting this question here, in hope someone will aid me. Either by fixing this code or sharing a code of his own. Explaining where I'm going wrong will be most appreciable.

Thanks a lot in advance, and sorry for this very long question,
Matan.

```
-----------------------EDIT------------------------
```

Below is my fixed code, which solves this question. Posting it incase one should ever need it :) Have fun !

```
public static long  M(long n, long j, long k)
{
    if (k == 0)
        return 0;
    if (k == 1)
        return sum(j,n);
    else 
    {
        long summation = 0;
        for (long i=j; i<=n; i++)
            summation += i*M(n, i+1, k-1);
        return summation;
    }
}
```

Comment: `double s1 = n/2*(n+1);` This line possibly contains a bug. Check the value of `s1` if `n` equals to `1`.

Comment: a bug indeed, thanks a lot! corrected and updated, however, doesn't yet solve the question.

Comment: why are `s1` and `s2` declared as double? You're just trying to calculate the sum between two integers.

Comment: It is to assure remainders are also taken into account, if odd numbers are involved.. just for caution.

Comment: Take in account that `long n = 5` means that line `double x = n / 2` will leave your `x` with value of 2.0 but not with 2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that u got ur answer and i really like ur algorithm but i cant control myself posting a better algorithm . here is the idea

`M(n,k) = coefficient of x^k in (1+x)(1+2*x)(1+3*x)...(1+n*x)`

u can solve above expression by divide and conquer algorithm [Click Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-two-polynomials-2/) to find how to multiply above expression and get polynomial function in the form of `ax^n + bx^(n-1)....+c`

overall algorithm  time complexity is  `O(n * log^2 n)`

and best part of above algorithm is

`in the attempt of finding solution for M(n,k) , u will find solution for M(n,x) where 1<=x<=n`

i hope it will be useful to know :)

Comment: DUDE! I just sat here waiting for this solution! Recursive solutions are great, but when we need really large values, recursion depths and running times just grow too fast.. Generating functions are a great approach, and I'm right now making sure to understand your solution! Appreciate it by a lot! And I truly wanna thank you for posting this! Thanks a lot! @polasairam

Comment: The answer posted here by the other user is incorrect. Works only on some cases. Hence I will accept your answer because I know it is correct indeed. I rewrote my algorithm and fixed the bugs, and it now works flawlessly, using my recursive method. I could not however implement yours. Are you able to write a program that solves it using your method? @polasairam

Comment: Try it using maps .. Map power to coefficient ..if no power exist .. Coefficient will be zero automatically .. Understood ? Give a try once

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your sum function : here is the correct formula:

```
public static long sum (long i, long n)
    {
        double s1 = n*(n+1)/2;
        double s2 = i*(i-1)/2;
        return (long)(s1-s2);
    }
```

Here the full solution :

```
    static int n = 5; 
    static long k = 3;
// no need to add n and k them inside your M function cause they are fixed.
    public static long M (long start) // start = 1
    {
        if(start > k) // if start is superior to k : like your example going from 1..3 , then you return 0
            return 0;
        int res = 0; // res of your function
        for(long i=start+1;i<n;i++){
            res+=start*i*sum(i+1,n); // here you take for example 1*2*sum(3,5) + 1*3*sum(4,5).... ect

        }

        return res+M(start+1); // return res and start again from start+1 wich would be 2.

    }
    public static long sum (long i, long n)
    {
        if(i>n)
            return 0;
        double s1 = n*(n+1)/2;
        double s2 = i*(i-1)/2;
        return (long)(s1-s2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(M(1));
    }
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Even after fixing my sum function, and correcting it here, the function still does not work.

Comment: check my edit @Matan, used your solving methode  *which i admit i liked it :) * you just had a problem in implementing your solution, hope this help you if need any question of why it works you can ask me.

Comment: Truly liked your sum function, even merely because it is clear that the sub-sums are composed of two sequential numbers, hence the product will for sure be divisible by 2, and it is clear from your declarations. Also, the function works great. Thanks a lot mate! :) @yahyaelfakir

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your algorithm, but you certainly messed up with your sum function. The problem you have is connected to type casting and division of integer numbers. Try something like this:

```
public static long sum (long i, long n)
{
    final long s1 = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    final long s2 = (i * i - i) / 2;
    return s1 - s2 ;
}
```